# Xcode Parsing JSON Returns NULL

Tags: ios, iphone, json, xcode, parsing

I'm having trouble parsing some JSON data, which contains nested arrays within nested arrays. A single JSON object that I am trying to parse looks like the following:

```
{  
  "date":1454284800,
  "exercises":[  
     {  
        "name":"Tricep Skull-Crushers",
        "sets":"5",
        "reps":"12",
        "time":"20",
        "weight":"",
        "notes":"testing testing again testing this app which is great "
     },
     {  
        "name":"Barbell Squat",
        "sets":"3",
        "reps":"12",
        "time":"",
        "weight":"45",
        "notes":"some notes"
     }
  ]
}
```

There may be any number of these objects that I am looking to parse into an `NSDictionary`. I have done this successfully with `JSON` data before, just not with nested arrays within nested arrays. I'm currently using a `NSURLSessionDataTask` to retrieve the data from the URL and once I have the data I convert it to an `NSDictionary` and split the data up into arrays using the following code:

```
        theDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];

        self.namesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.setsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.repsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (NSDictionary *dict in theDictionary) {

            [self.namesArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"name"]];
            [self.setsArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"sets"]];
            [self.repsArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"reps"]];
        }
```

This code works when previously parsing JSON data and whilst I can the data and response string returned correctly, whenever I try and convert the data to an `NSDictionary` or an `NSArray` it keeps returning `NULL`. Like I said this code has worked before for parsing `JSON` but not with so many nested arrays within the `JSON` object.

Can anyone offer me some advice on how to achieve this?

EDIT:

I've posted the full response string below, which I am receiving with multiple objects of the example above. In case anyone wants to view this in [JSON Editor Online](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) to see how a full response should look:

```
[{"date":1454284800,"exercises":[{"name":"Tricep Skull-Crushers","sets":"5","reps":"12","time":"20","weight":"","notes":"testing testing again testing this app which is great "},{"name":"Barbell Squat","sets":"","reps":"","time":"","weight":"","notes":""}]},{"date":1454284800,"exercises":[{"name":"Tricep Skull-Crushers","sets":"5","reps":"12","time":"20","weight":"","notes":"testing testing again testing this app which is great "},{"name":"Barbell Squat","sets":"","reps":"","time":"","weight":"","notes":""},{"name":"Arnold Press","sets":"5","reps":"12","time":"","weight":"","notes":""}]},{"date":1454112000,"exercises":[{"name":"Single Arm Row","sets":"3","reps":"10","time":"","weight":"","notes":""},{"name":"Tricep Rope Pull-Downs","sets":"3","reps":"10","time":"","weight":"","notes":""}]},{"date":1454112000,"exercises":[{"name":"Single Arm Row","sets":"3","reps":"10","time":"","weight":"","notes":""},{"name":"Tricep Rope Pull-Downs","sets":"3","reps":"10","time":"","weight":"","notes":""}]},{"date":1454112000,"exercises":[{"name":"Single Arm Row","sets":"3","reps":"10","time":"","weight":"","notes":""},{"name":"Tricep Rope Pull-Downs","sets":"3","reps":"10","time":"","weight":"","notes":""}]}]
```

Comment: there is no key `workout_name` or `workout` in your JSON response

Comment: So what does the `NSError` object say?

Comment: `for (NSDictionary *dict in theDictionary[@"exercises"])`?? What's NULL exactly?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik sorry those keys were in reference to another part of the app which is working successfully. I copied and pasted the working code from that part of my app. I have edit the question now thanks for pointing that out but that isn't the issue I'm afraid.

Comment: @trojanfoe The error says "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.".

Comment: So that sounds like you aren't loading it correctly from the server.

Comment: print your jsonData to see if it is valid json string, e.g. `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`

Comment: It does print out correctly I've already checked.

Comment: That is valid JSON so there is no reason that won't parse.  Where is the definition of `theDictionary`?  Why are you using `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers`?

Comment: The dictionary is just a standard NSDictionary and I'm using NSJSONReadingMutableContainers just because that seemed to be the standard options and it worked in another section of my app. Should I be using another options type?

Comment: But of course the top-level object in the JSON is an array, not a dictionary, so you need to correct that.  And you don't need `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` so make it `0` instead.  Use a local variable, like this: `NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization ...];`

Comment: I've tried to us the following to create an array out of the JSON using 0 as options and then split that up into individual dictionaries but it still both return NULL.

`NSError *jsonError;
            NSArray *theArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];

            NSDictionary *theDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
            theDict = [theArray objectAtIndex:0];`

Comment: I don't see why that is, given the JSON you have posted, which is valid.  There isn't much else to say; this is a very commonly-used method.  But what do you mean by "still both return NULL"?  What "both"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we finally figured out the issue. It appeared that JSON has an issue parsing line breaks (\n). What I had to do is turn that JSON data into a string, remove any line breaks (\n), then turn the string back into data and convert it to an NSDictionary. It's kind of annoying that this has taken over a day to figure out being something pretty simple but here's the final code that I'm using. Hope this helps anyone stuck in a similar issue.

```
        NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        jsonString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "];

        NSData *dataWithoutLineBreaks = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSError *jsonError;
        NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataWithoutLineBreaks options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];
```

Answer (score -1):

Every thing is OK in Your code, just a minor change in for loop

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in theDictionary[@"exercises"]) 
{

        [self.namesArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"name"]];
        [self.setsArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"sets"]];
        [self.repsArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"reps"]];




    }
```

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't working as I'm not even able to convert the data to an NSDictionary or an NSArray in the first place.

Comment: check your nsdata having any value or it is nil

Comment: Yes the data is returned correctly and I can even convert it to a string to confirm it. The issue is turning that data into an NSDictionary or even an NSArray.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between valueForKey and objectForKey? Why do you use both of them? And why not just theDictionary [@"exercises"] ?

Answer (score -1):

This is your answer by writing in swift :

```
do { 
     let json = try NSJsonSerialization.jsonObjectWithDat(jsondata, options: .AllFragments)
for var i = 0 ; i < json.count ; i++ {
    if let item = json[i] {
        if let date = item["date"]{//do anything}
        if let experience = item["experience"] {
           for ex in experience {
              let name = experience["name"]
              let step = experience["step"]
              let reps = experience["reps"]
              let time = experience["time"]
              let weight = experience["weight"]
              let notes = experience["notes"]
            }
      }
  } catch err as NSError {
     print(err)
  }
```